# Не переключается таб

Tags: javascript, html, css

В чем проблема, не переключается таб.
Хочу сделать таб через for of. При нажатии не добавляется класс active и выдает ошибку "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add') at click.onclick"

```js
const button = document.querySelectorAll('a');


const content = document.querySelectorAll('.tab_content');


for(let click of button) {

    click.onclick = () => {
        for(let item of content) {
            item.classList.remove('active');
        }
        content.classList.add('active');
    };
};
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    max-width: 100vw;
    background-color:#316676 ;
}


 content {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
 } 

 .block {
    max-width: 500px;
 }

.tab_text > a {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}

 .tab_text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
 }

 .tab_content {
    padding-top: 60px;
    color: #83ffff;
    display: none;
 }

 .active {
    display: block;
 }
```

```html
<content>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="tab_text">
      <a href="#" id="first">Сюда</a>
      <a href="#" id="two">Сюда</a>
      <a href="#" id="three">Сюда</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab_content active" data-tab-name="tab-1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit consequatur recusandae numquam. Tempore soluta laudantium, suscipit reiciendis, necessitatibus doloribus, blanditiis iusto dolores laboriosam dolorem nihil qui porro quasi ut expedita?
    </div>
    <div class="tab_content" data-tab-name="tab-2">
      2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit consequatur recusandae numquam. Tempore soluta laudantium, suscipit reiciendis, necessitatibus doloribus, blanditiis iusto dolores laboriosam dolorem nihil qui porro quasi ut expedita?
    </div>
    <div class="tab_content" data-tab-name="tab-3">
      3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit consequatur recusandae numquam. Tempore soluta laudantium, suscipit reiciendis, necessitatibus doloribus, blanditiis iusto dolores laboriosam dolorem nihil qui porro quasi ut expedita?
    </div>
  </div>
</content>
```

Comment: Правильно пишет. Что, по-вашему. возвращает querySelector**All** ?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` возвращает объект `NodeList` ,  а не `HTMLDivElement`

Comment: А что мне использовать?

Comment: @dxxdly вероятно, там надо добавить активный класс блоку с текстом, а как вы определяете которому добавлять? Для начала, сформулируйте на русском, потом можете перенести на js